# How Agda determines a type is impossible

Tags: agda, dependent-type

So I'm trying to understand why this code gives yellow highlighting around the ()

```
data sometype : List ℕ → Set where
  constr : (l1 l2 : List ℕ)(n : ℕ) → sometype (l1 ++ (n ∷ l2))

somef : sometype [] → ⊥
somef ()
```

But this does not

```
data sometype : List ℕ → Set where
  constr : (l1 l2 : List ℕ)(n : ℕ) → sometype (n ∷ (l1 ++ l2))

somef : sometype [] → ⊥
somef ()
```

Both seem to such that sometype [] is empty, but Agda can't figure the first one out? Why? What is the code behind this doing? And Can I define somef in a way to make the first definition work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agda can't assume anything about arbitrary functions like `++`. Suppose we defined `++` the following way:

```
_++_ : {A : Set} → List A → List A → List A
xs ++ ys = []
```

In this case, `sometype [] → ⊥` isn't provable, and accepting the `()` absurd pattern would be an error.

In your second example, the index of `sometype` must be of the form `n ∷ (l1 ++ l2)`, which is a constructor expression, since `_∷_` is a list constructor. Agda can safely infer that a `_∷_`-constructed list can never be equal to `[]`. In general, distinct constructors can be seen as impossible to unify.

What Agda can do with function applications is reducing them as far as possible. In some cases reduction yields constructor expressions, in other cases it doesn't, and we need to write additional proofs.

To prove `sometype [] → ⊥`, we should do some generalization first. We can't pattern match on a value of `sometype []` (because of the `++` in the type index), but we can match on `sometype xs` for some abstracted `xs`. So, our lemma says the following:

```
someF' : ∀ xs → sometype xs → xs ≡ [] → ⊥
someF' .(n  ∷ l2)           (constr [] l2 n) ()
someF' .(n' ∷ l1 ++ n ∷ l2) (constr (n' ∷ l1) l2 n) ()
```

In other words, `∀ xs → sometype xs → xs ≢ []`. We can derive the desired proof from this:

```
someF : sometype [] → ⊥
someF p = someF' [] p refl
```

Comment: is the dot about "Irrelevance"? Can you give an explanation of what the dot means?

Comment: I found "dotted patterns" on the internet, but I still don't quite understand. the Dependently Typed Programming in Agda pdf says you do this when the pattern can be deduced, but does the compiler actually check this must be the only case?

Comment: Dot signals that the variables inside the (dotted) pattern are introduced in some other pattern. Each pattern  variable must be introduced exactly once, and if we want to use the same same variable elsewhere (because type dependencies force values to be equal in patterns), we can do it inside  dotted patterns.

Comment: BTW, dotted patterns are automatically expanded in the Emacs Agda interface if you hit `C-c` with the to-be-expanded binding in a hole. Here are the other [Emacs keys](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Docs.EmacsModeKeyCombinations).

Comment: Agda does know the definition of _++_ and will use its clauses as rewrite rules. It is true though that since no rewrite rule matches (l1 ++ (n ∷ l2)) Agda only knows that it's equal to itself.